# svn_load_dirs.pl - where to download it from? definitive official place?

Tags: svn, download, location, where-clause

Where can I download svn_load_dirs.pl definitive official place, please.
Thanks.

Doesn't appear to be in SVN *source* release:
http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release

Not bundled with uberSVN, a SVN installation

Google search gives no answers

The O'Reilly "red book" on SVN discusses the use of the tool but not where to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should maybe get it directly from the repository:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib

The script is here:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_load_dirs/

Comment: +1 Accepted. Now why didn't they themselves make it that obvious? :)